# Rails application separated in 2 layers (data reception / data reading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scalability

I have an application with 2 different layers:

- first layer: ruby tcp server receiving a lot of data
  This one is a very light application running EvenMachine, it only receives the data, make some calculation on them and then sends them over http to the second layer
- second layer: rails application providing user visualisation of data
  I use thin as the application server
  This layer receives information from the first layer and store them in the database. This layer is the user front-end. Models and migrations are defined here.

I did not merge the 2 layers as I need to have a tcp (not http server) as entry point.
I'm wondering what is the most efficient and scalable approach then:

- send the data from layer one to layer two via http once they are formatted correctly
- directly put the data in the database form the first layer using ActiveRecord or pg gem. Each time EventMachine receives a request, it passes it to ActiveRecord which only needs to write a single record in the database. Is there a risk of blocking IO if a lot of requests are received ?
- rewrite the first layer on node.js and use node-postgres to ensure non blocking IO.

What is the best approach to insure scalability and non blocking IO ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think there is a non-blocking mysql gem based on event-machine, though I'm not sure if it is still maintained or not.
2. What about the 'calculation' in the first layer? Is it gonna be slow? A single MRI process can not utilize multicore because of the presence of GIL, so you will probably need multiple processes in layer one and a load balancer in front of it.
3. Instead of having layer one to do the calculation and layer two storing something into database, there might be another approach: layer one receives the data, stores it in redis as a 'job'. Another worker process fetches the "job", do the calculation and stores it into database, and that's how Resque works. So layer two only do the normal http things. But still, you are talking about 'a lot of data', so storing it into redis might take some time as well, but the point is to move some heavy job to background processes so that either layer one or layer two can continue processing other requests.
4. I wrote some code to compare node.js and event-machine(mostly focusing on CPU usage), there isn't really much difference.

Comment: 2/ the calculation in the first layer are very limited (mainly text parsing). I have planned to add a load balancer. 3/ I will need the data to be added in database in real time. Do I run the same risk of blocking IO when saving in the Database each new data received even if saved with an additional job ?

Comment: 4/ As node-postgres is non-blocking IO, I though that could be a good alternative then. What do you think ?

Comment: Well if receiving & storing data is basically all that matters, why receiving it & transferring it to layer two & layer two 'transferring ' it to database? Why not layer one receiving it & let other threads to do the rest of the job? At least it saves one transfer.

Comment: This is what I'm wondering actually :) My first guess was to let layer one save data to database using ActiveRecord but if 100+ data are received at the same time, will ActiveRecord / Postgres add some blocking IO ?

Comment: So that's why you'll need to have other threads to do the storing job:) 
As for node.js, I don't see the difference with event-machine, and it suffers single core problem too. With event-machine, you can always go with jruby if you want.

Comment: I mostly see the problem between the postgres drivers: ActiveRecord/pg in ruby vs node-postgres in nodejs. I maybe wrong but node-postgres is  non blocking, is ActiveRecord / pg also ?

Comment: I don't think so. You can try em_postgresql but I'm not sure about the stability of it. Anyway, you can still achieve the same thing with event-machine's event_callback or ruby fiber, it's basically the same thing to me. My point is if you already have a running version of 'layer one', it seems much more effort to rewrite it in node.js